# SQL: select max value when converting from long to wide format

Tags: sql, group-by, pivot

I have a table like the following and I need to convert it from this long format to wide and at the same time, I need to select the action value corresponding to max score:

```
user_id time_id val0 val1 val2 action_value score
1       1       1    0     0   0            0.6
1       1       0    1     0   1            0.3
1       1       0    0     1   2            0.3
1       2       1    0     0   0            0.7
1       2       0    1     0   1            0.4
1       2       0    0     1   2            0.3
2       1       1    0     0   0            0.4
2       1       0    1     0   1            0.5
2       1       0    0     1   2            0.4
```

the desired output is:

```
 user_id time_id  score_0 score_1 score_2 action_value
 1       1           0.6.    0.3.   0.3   0
 1       2           0.7.    0.4    0.3.  0 
 2       1           0.4     0.5    0.4.  1
```

the SQL I use do not have PIVOT, so I cannot use PIVOT. And I know that I can use conditional aggregation to convert the data from long format to wide format but I am not sure how I can also select the action_value column corresponding to the max score.

Comment: Shouldn't the first row be `0.7`, `0.4`, `0.3` instead of `0.6`, `0.3`, `0.3`?

Comment: How do you compute `action_value`? It's not clear from the example.

Comment: add your database type and explain how you computer action_value

Comment: val0, val1, val2 are the one-hot encoding version of action_value. i edited the typo as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a subquery, then `greatest()` (if your database supports it):

```
select 
    t.*,
    case greatest(score0, score1, score2)
        when score0 then 0
        when score1 then 1
        when score2 then 2
    end action_value
from (
    select
        user_id,
        time_id,
        max(case when actual_value = 0 then score end) score0,
        max(case when actual_value = 1 then score end) score1,
        max(case when actual_value = 2 then score end) score2
    from mytable
    group by user_id, time_id
) t
```